# micro-service always connects to localhost for consul

Tags: jhipster, consul

I have generated a microservice configured for consul with jhipster 4.6.2.
I'm running Consul with Docker (with Virtualbox).

As a result, it is not running on localhost (but e.g. with 192.168.99.100).

Hence I modified application-dev.yml of my microservice to set the host like this :

cloud:
consul:
discovery:
prefer-ip-address: true
host: 192.168.99.100
port: 8500

... but when I start the micro-service, it is still trying to connect to localhost (i.e. the property below is not taken into account).
Then I got this exception :

com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException:
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:
Connect to localhost:8500 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, localhost/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1] failed:
Connection refused

Any idea ?

thanks !

My config jhipster:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "org.fge.msconsul"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.6.2",
    "baseName": "msconsul",
    "packageName": "org.fge.msconsul",
    "packageFolder": "org/fge/msconsul",
    "serverPort": "8082",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "consul",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "replaced-by-jhipster-info",
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn"
  }
}
</details>

##### **JDL for the Entity configuration(s) `entityName.json` files generated in the `.jhipster` directory**

##### **Environment and Tools**

java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)

node: v7.4.0

npm: 5.0.3

bower: 1.8.0

gulp:
[22:45:50] CLI version 3.9.1

yeoman: 2.0.0

yarn: 0.27.5

Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be

docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb

Execution complete
```

Comment: As a side note, JHipster does not support node 7.x, we support only LTS versions as documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Cloud has a [bootstrap phase](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_the_bootstrap_application_context) from which it can load configuration properties from the external sources.

`src/main/resources/bootstrap*.yml` is the file where you must configure how to connect to Consul.

Comment: Thanks Gaël, it works now indeed! Maybe it would be helpful to remove this consul's host prop from application-(dev|prod).xml since it is not supposed to be located there apparently (or maybe it must be set on both locations, I did not test)

Comment: When using JHipster Registry rather than Consul, it's required for running app in dev without a registry instance running. I did not test for Consul, maybe it's not the same and application.yml should not include this Consul props

Comment: That's my mistake as I coded this part ! I'm pretty sure the property is not needed in application.yml at all. Even when not using a registry, it will still read the bootstrap.yml and use a bootstrap phase as long as spring cloud config dependency is present. So it can safely be removed. @user1458153 if you could submit a PR that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can also mention in application.properties the consul host like below, i have confirmed that this works

```
spring.cloud.consul.host=http://hostname
spring.cloud.consul.port=8500
```

the best way to mention this is bootstrap.yml which is loaded first before any .properties are loaded